# Asn1c Compiler is not compiling EXTERNAL type

Tags: parser-generator, asn.1

I wanted to know if anybody has successfully compiled a data structure containing EXTERNAL type with asn1c compiler (http://lionet.info/asn1c/blog/) ? I have successfully compiled the presentation layer using asn1c and used to decode packets in my code but I am unable to compile ACSE layer because the compiler whines for EXTERNAL.h file, which doesn't get generated in the compilation process and thus I am unable to use the compiled files.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not tried EXTERNAL in the lionet.info asn1 compiler, but the OSS Nokalva asn1 compiler supports the ASN.1 EXTERNAL type without any difficulty.  You can download a free trial of the OSS ASN.1 compiler from http://www.oss.com/asn1/products/asn1-download.html.

Paul